# Creating and saving cross-section images from 3D objects

Tags: 3d-view, 2d

I want to save the cross-section images of 3D cylindrical objects which have bulk and empty spaces in them.

I couldn't find any question/answer to this here, while most of the previous questions are about visualizing the cross-section or taking slices with some thicknesses.

Answer (score 5):

### Shader

You can get an object's position in a shader and use it as a transparency mask:

[image: shader example]

[image: Demo]

Note: If you are using only a Principled BSDF shader to begin with, you can plug the *Greater Than* output directly to the Principled's Alpha input instead of mixing the Principled to a Transparent BSDF.

You can move the object in any position and rotation you like, and you can use this on as many different shaders you want.

It's also quite easy to adapt it so to have a slice:

[image: slice]

### Geometry

You can use a difference boolean modifier targeting a cube, so ro physically remove the mesh where the cube is:

[image: boolean]

[image: demo gif]

You need to add the boolean on each object that you want to section. If you have multiple objects you need to copy it to, you can select them, then <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> the one that already have the boolean modifier, and hit <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> > Copy Modifiers.

I also highly advise enabling these options:

[image: options]

You can choose the material of the filling by adding any material you like on the boolean mesh target. Just don't forget to disable this object for rendering. If you want no filling, give it a transparent shader and it will look as the previous method.

The advantage of this method is that it fills the holes (if you need to), and you can more easily control in an interactive way how and where the cuts happen.

To have a slice, set the boolean to Intersect.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I think I was able to do it, but I might have a different problem in my mesh -I couldn't see the holes inside it properly. Thank you!